# Automatically reusing existing entity in ManyToMany/ManyToOne relationship (JPA)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

JPA and Hibernate are used to retrieve and persist entities. There is a `User` table and it contains a `Country`, which is represented in another table.

I would like to insert a new user into `User` table. This new user is from country that is already inserted in the `Country` table. To assign the new user the existing country I could retrieve the country object from the database and set it to the `User` object - it works as expected, a relationship is created between user and the existing country, no new rows are inserted to `Country` table.

Is it possible to get the same behavior without retrieving `Country` objects from database, based just on the value that I set to the `Country` object in the JPA entity in Java?

For example:

```
User user = new User("test user");
user.setCountry(new Country("USA"));
entityManager.persist(user);
```

I would like JPA/Hibernate to automatically check if the country, which code is USA (code is saved in a column in Country table and it is unique), already exists in the database. If it does - use the existing Country object so that a new entry in the database would not be created, if it does not exist - insert a new country in the Country table.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can from User entity create 2 mapping related to country.

```
@Column
private String country_code;
// and
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private Country country;
```

Before save new data you only need to setup the country_code instead of the entity, after save you can do `entityManager.refresh(user)`, it will load the `@ManyToOne` field for you

So I guess

```
User user = new User("test user");
user.setCountry_code("USA");
entityManager.persist(user);
entityManager.refresh(user);
```